# Spring Cloud Config Server via HTTPS

Tags: java, spring, ssl, https, config

I want to secure my spring cloud config server using https protocol but I always get weird error during start tomcat server. Btw. when I disable ssl application run correct without any errors.

Maybe someone can help me?

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1008) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:227) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:263) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:195) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:297) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552) [spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.9.RELEASE]
        at xxx.ConfigServerApplication.main(ConfigServerApplication.java:12) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [config-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [config-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) [config-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) [config-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Stream closed
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:99) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:218) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1124) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1210) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:585) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1005) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.ensureOpen(InflaterInputStream.java:67) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.ZipInflaterInputStream.read(ZipInflaterInputStream.java:52) ~[config-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
        at java.security.DigestInputStream.read(DigestInputStream.java:124) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:658) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
        at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.security.KeyStoreUtil.load(KeyStoreUtil.java:69) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getStore(SSLUtilBase.java:217) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate.getCertificateKeystore(SSLHostConfigCertificate.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:283) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:247) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Tomcat can't load your keystore, but the reason why is unclear. Re-check all the ssl properties that refer to your keystore, e.g. the path and password. If it's in a jar, take it out and try a direct file pathname to see if that's it.

Comment: Did you solve this? I am getting the exact same error!

Comment: Unfortunately not